# SQL - MS Access Form design - add data of ISA relationships

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I'm taking a DBMS course and I need to design and build my own DB. I have a database for a hospital where doctors,nurses,support staff etc are in a ISA relationship to an Employee entity with the rest of the data like the name, address , salary and the rest of the employee data.

Designing a form, I want to be able to add an employee with all of their data in one form. 
Is there a way to do a "conditional table" of sorts where if i select "doctor" from a drop-down i get to add to the doctor table too, and same for the rest of the entities under the ISA relationship?

Thx!

Comment: The discriminator (what enables you to distinguish types) is just a database cloumn and a GUI variable. The fact that a Doctor is an Employee and that a Nurse is also an Employee may be utilized by making a base class for employee and let eahc type inherit this base class. Whe you persist the data, you have to design methods to do Employee.Save(...some data structure...),

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, when dealing with data, you do NOT flip or switch tables for a given form or relatonal database design.

So, for example. If I have a table of customers. Well, now if I want to mark some of the customers as plumbers, and others as doctors? I don't create two tables.

All I would do is add ONE column to that customers table and it would simply allow me to set the type of customer. The reason for this design is "many" but some significant reasons are:

For each new type of customer, you would not create a new table. Worse, all of the forms, the reports, the SQL, the code you write? Well, all of that code  would have to be modified EACH time you create a new table. So, you SIMPLY cannot adopt a design in which the concept of changing a table is part of that process.

Forms are bound to ONE table. For related data, you in most cases will use a sub form.

So, think of even a accounting system. They can have huge numbers of customers, and as a result, you can "query" that table to give you all customers. Or you might ask how many accounting firms are in the customer list. Or make a report that summeries by customer type a "count" of each type of customer.

So,  buidling forms, or reports? They cannot on the fly "change" the tables they are using.

So, in place of a tables called:
SalesJan
SalesFeb
SalesMar
etc.

Well, now you can't query sales from Jan to mar, because the data is in different tables.

So, what you do is have ONE table called "sales", and you add ONE column of the date. Now, at the start of each new month, you don't have to create a new table.

Now, of course in some cases it makes sense to create a separate table. For example, a table of customers, and a table of employees in a database is just fine. It makes sense in this case to use two tables, since the information about a customer and what they can do and the kind of information is VERY different then how you would deal with employees.

So, with above? Well, if I need to print mailing labels for all customers and all employees? That would require two different reports. And very likely the table structure for the two tables is different.

Bottom line:
If you working on design or form or report? And you needing to try and change the table that the form/report/code etc is going to operate on? This is a sign that your design approach has gone complete off the rails and is the wrong design.

So, in the case of doctors, nurses etc.? Well, they are all hospital staff, and MOST of the basic information about such employees will be common, much the same, and thus a SINGLE table of "employees" makes the most sense. You would only need a nice "employee type" combo box on that one form, and thus you can add/enter/edit/search any employee in that one table.

The fact that you "want to search" for a employee show that all these people "are" employees and thus belong in one table. And the basic information about all employees is going to be the same anyway. If you find you are attempting to create a new table but with near identical structures over and over, then just like a new table for each month sales, or a new table for each new kind of employee? Simply add the "one" column that allows you to make that distinguish, and not a whole new table.

Now one COULD  even attempt to put patients in the same table, but then again, dealing with patents as opposed employees is a considerable different kind of "thing".

So employees are employees - even different kinds. (manager, cleaning staff etc.).
And patients are patients - even different kinds (long term care, emergency etc.).

Comment: thanks for the detailed response! apart from a tag such as "doctor" , "nurse", etc, each one of those entities has an additional two or three variables that are unique to them. for example - doctors might have area of expertise and nurses might have qualifications or room numbers they are in charge of. How do i handle this, if i want to create a form to add a new employee?

Comment: Then build a child table of qualifications. You might even have that one column in that table that sets the qualification kind or type. So over time, you can add as many new types of qualifications as you want, and not have to change your table design. So, some doctors might have 5 or 25 types of qualifications - you just be adding rows to this child table. That same child table of qualifications of course can be used for any type of staff, from nurses, to even staff trained for certain types of equipment etc. So one staff record, and a child table of their "many" types of qualifications.